# pyspark: counter part of like() method in dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

Is there any counter method for like() in spark dataframe (something as notLike())?

Or is there any other way to do it except using the traditonal SQL query?

I want to do just the opposite of the following:

```
df.where(col("_c2").like("XY6%")).show(5)
```

Comment: just `df.where(not(col("_c2").like("XY6%"))).show(5)`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It worked :)

I had to use the negation operator (~) instead of the 'not' keyword.

```
df.where(~ col("_c2").like("XY6%")).show(5)
```

Comment: how to do it with for two substrings: i.e. `df.where(~ col("_c2").like("XY6%") and ~ col("_c2").like("XY6%"))` ?

Answer (score 2):

Or you can do :

```
df.where( col("_c2").like("XY6%") == False ).show(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

For two condition we can do this way:

```
df.where((~col("_c2").like("XY6%")) & (~col("_c2").like("X6%")))
```