# TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to run this code in pyspark and the following error appears:

```py
data.filter(
    (((F.col('post_v1_web_page_name') == 'escritorio:publica:general:formulario:formulario crm tarjetas bbva:confirmacion') | (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name') == 'escritorio:publica:general:formulario:formulario crm tarjetas bbva paca:confirmacion') |  (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name') == 'escritorio:publica:general:formulario:tarjeta tres meses sin:confirmacion') | (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name') == 'escritorio:publica:general:formulario:tarjetas premium:confirmacion') | (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name') == 'escritorio:publica:general:formulario:tarjeta repsol credito:confirmacion') | (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name') == 'escritorio:publica:personas:tarjeta repsol:credito:tarjetas:confirmacion') | (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name') == 'escritorio:privada:particulares:tarjeta credito:3 estudio de la solicitud:1 direccion entrega'))
    | ((F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%formulario:formulario%")) & (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%tarjeta%")) & (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%crm%")) & (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%confirma%")))
    | ((F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%escritorio:publica:personas%")) & (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%tarjetas:credito%")) & (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%confirmacion%")))
    | ((F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%responsive-tablet:publica:personas%")) & (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%tarjetas:credito%")) & (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%confirmacion%"))))
    | (((((F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%formulario:tarjetas de credito%")) | (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%formulario:tarjetas repsol%")) | (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%web-movil:publica:general:formulario:tarjeta repsol credito%")) | (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%web-movil:tarjetas:tarjeta despues%")) | (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%web-movil:formulario:tarjeta viat bbva%")) | (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%web-movil:publica:particulares:formulario:tarjeta viat%")) | (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%web-movil:formulario:tarjeta refe dorada%")) | (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%web-movil:formulario:tarjetas motor credito bbva%")) | (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%web-movil:formulario:credito tarjeta viajes movil%")) | (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%web-movil:formulario:tarjetas de credito tarjetas bbva")) | (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%web-movil:formulario:tarjetas de credito 3 meses sin%")) | (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name') == 'responsive-mobile:publica:personas:tarjetas:credito:tarjeta respsol:finalizado') | (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name') == 'responsive:mobile:publica:personas:tarjeta repsol:credito:tarjetas:nombre:finalizado'))
    & (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%finalizado%"))
    & (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').notlike("%debito%"))) 
    | ((F.col('post_v1_web_page_name') == 'web-movil:formulario:otros:2 finalizado') & (F.col('post_v47_appl_typology_name') == 'TMM')) 
    | ((F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%publica:personas%")) & (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%tarjetas:credito%")) & (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%finalizado%")))
    | ((F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%card request form%")) & (F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%confirmation%")))
      )))
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you try to call a not available function on one or more `F.col` instances. E.g., see [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185594/column-object-not-callable-spark?rq=1) I think it might be the `notlike` as far as I am aware this is [not available in Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44177236/pyspark-counter-part-of-like-method-in-dataframe).

A general note: The condition you are developing is very difficult to maintain and understand for other developers and probably also for you. I would recommend splitting the conditions into multiple variables and combine them step by step.
e.g.

```
condition_is_required_pattern = F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%finalizado%") | F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%otherRegex%")
condition_not_illegal_pattern = ~ F.col('post_v1_web_page_name').like("%debito%")
data_filterd = data.filter(
      condition_is_required_pattern 
      & condition_not_illegal_pattern
)
```